Is there any deeper significance to the March 14, 2018 date shown in Deadpool & Wolverine?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), there's a scene where Deadpool is

interviewing with Happy Hogan to join the Avengers in Earth-616, the Sacred Timeline.

The specific date shown is March 14, 2018.

I've looked into the importance of this date, but most articles I've found simply state that it's set a few months before the events of Avengers: Infinity War. This intrigues me because MCU productions typically avoid pinpointing exact dates for events.
Even the Marvel Studios' The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline book rarely provides specific dates, usually opting for months or seasons instead. There are plenty of other ways to indicate that this scene takes place before Infinity War, so the decision to show an exact date intrigues me.
I'm curious if there's any special meaning behind March 14, 2018, beyond just setting the scene a few months prior to Infinity War. Is there any deeper significance to why this particular date might have been chosen?

Part of the joke of the scene is Wade expecting to meet Tony Stark, and Happy making it very clear that's he's not going to allow that. It had to be before Infinity War for that to work, due to [redacted spoilers for Infinity War].

No idea if it has relevance in the film(s), but March 14th each year is Pi Day (because π = 3.14...).

Besides signaling that the meeting occurred before the events of Infinity War transpired, it seems that the specific date of March 14th 2018 is the same date that Disney announced, per New York Times, that it was preparing to integrate assets from its purchase of 21st Century Fox. It seems that timeline continuity and a nod to the Fox takeover inspired the specific date. Article linked below.
https://web.archive.org/web/20180314231057/https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/14/business/media/walt-disney-21st-century-fox.html

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

Despicable Deadpool 296 release date. The End is Nigh. The conclusion of Deadpool's Bucket List.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

That's interesting. Does this comic book storyline have any connection to the plot of Deadpool & Wolverine? Like, did Deadpool & Wolverine borrow any plot elements from this particular comic issue or story arc?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
